# Conditional cast from UIViewController always succeeds | Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, casting, option-type

What am I doing wrong here? This still functions fine, but I would like to get rid of the yellow warning if I can help it. The warning is on the "if" statement. If I remove the "?" on "as", then the code won't even run... it requires it yet complains about it.

**The warning:**

```
Conditional cast from 'UIViewController' to 'UIViewController' always succeeds
```

**The code:**

```
class FadeInPushSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    
    var animated: Bool = true
    
    override func perform() {
        
        if let sourceViewController = self.source as? UIViewController, let destinationViewController = self.destination as? UIViewController {
            
            let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
            
            transition.type = CATransitionType.fade; sourceViewController.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")
            sourceViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false)
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: just remove ```as? UIViewController``` casting.

Comment: Will it still make sure that what's calling it is a UIViewController and that where it's going is a UIViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to cast it to UIViewController because properties source and destinations is UIViewController already

```
open var source: UIViewController { get }

open var destination: UIViewController { get }
```

You seeing this warning because you cast from not Optional UIViewController to optional UIViewController.

When you remove  `as?` your code isn't running because you trying to unwrap not optional property.

`Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UIViewController'`

You should remove `if` do something like that:

```
final class FadeInPushSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
var animated: Bool = true

override func perform() {
    
    let sourceViewController = self.source
    let destinationViewController = self.destination
    
    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    
    transition.type = CATransitionType.fade; sourceViewController.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")
    sourceViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false)

}
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you for taking a moment to help me out!